# ggiraph y-axis alignment issue when changing fonts

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, ggiraph

I'm using `ggiraph` to plot my `ggplot` object in my shiny dashboard that I deploy on shinyapps.io. My dashboard works well locally, but the font change that happens as a result of deploying on shinyapps.io results in y-axis alignment problem. At first I thought the problem is using `hjust = 1` in my dashboard, but the example below is on my own computer, without using dashboard, only with font changes. I'm using the same example as [ggiraph book - Chapter 3](https://www.ardata.fr/ggiraph-book/fonts.html):

```
font_family_exists("Open Sans")
[1] TRUE

library(gdtools)
register_gfont("Open Sans")
[1] TRUE

addGFontHtmlDependency(family = "Open Sans")


dat <- mtcars
dat$carname <- row.names(dat)

gg <- ggplot(dat, aes(drat, carname)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_minimal(base_family = "sans")

validated_fonts(list(sans = "Open Sans"))

$sans
[1] "Open Sans"

$serif
[1] "Times New Roman"

$mono
[1] "Courier New"

$symbol
[1] "Symbol"
```

Running `ggiraph` on the object itself works perfectly:

```
girafe(ggobj = gg)
```

[image]

But adding the font changes the alignment:

```
girafe(ggobj = gg, fonts = list(sans = "Open Sans"))
```

[image]

I'm using R 4.3.2, and ggiraph 0.8.7.

Just wondering why the labels get messed up as soon as the font changes, and whether there is any way to keep the fonts the same when a dashboard is employed on shinyapps.io.

Thanks!

Comment: The default font is fixed width. The font that you changed to is a variable width font.

Comment: @G5W Thanks. Do you know how I can fix this so that when the dashboard is employed, proper font is set?

Comment: You need to use the method described here: https://www.ardata.fr/ggiraph-book/fonts.html#shiny-illustration